# Cannot implement interface member using derived type

Tags: c#, interface

Lets assume I've got a class Called `StreetModel` that implements an interface called `IStreetModel`:

```
public class StreetModel: IStreetModel {
    // Properties go here
}
```

Said IStreetModel looks like so:

```
public interface IStreetModel {
    // Properties go here
}
```

Now, say I have another interface called `ILocationModel` that contains a property of type `IStreetModel`:

```
public interface ILocationModel {
    IStreetModel Street { get; }
}
```

And this `ILocationModel` interface is implemented by a class called `LocationModel`:

```
public class LocationModel: ILocationModel {
    public StreetModel Street { get; } // This is where my query is
}
```

My Question: Within `LocationModel`, why can't I implement `StreetModel` even though it implements `IStreetModel`. Why does the compiler want `IStreetModel` specifically? It's confusing for me because in almost every other scenario within my program (except for collections) I can interchange usage of the two. Why not here?

Error Message:

> 'LocationModel' does not implement interface member
> 'ILocationModel.Street'. 'LocationModel.Street' cannot implement
> 'ILocationModel.Street' because it does not have the matching return
> type of 'IStreetModel'.

Comment: The type of the property must match the exact type declared in the interface, thus you must write: `public IStreetModel Street { get; }` and you can also provide `public StreetModel StreetModelInstance => Street as StreetModel;`

Comment: I think that's the rule of implementing an interface in a class. The signatures of methods, properties, delegates etc must match the ones are declared in the interface

Comment: This begs the question why do you _want_ to have the concrete `StreetModel` instead of the interface? ie, if we understood what you're trying to achieve there might be a better way

Comment: `public class LocationModel : ILocationModel
    {
        public StreetModel Street { get; }IStreetModel ILocationModel.Street => this.Street;` Explicit interface implementation will get you what you want.

Comment: @Jamiec I suppose the main problem is that my interfaces and models are in different projects. Naturally, the model project knows about the interface project but not the other way around because of... you know... circular dependencies n' all.

So I suppose the real issue was how do I create an interface (in the interface project) that contains classes in the model project. This was the best that I could do. Maybe I should have made that the question here... How best to implement such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your actual question ("why doesn't it compile?") is: The c# language requires that a return type for an implemented interface member matches exactly. That's the way the language was designed.

This was fixed by c# 9 in some cases, but not for interface implementations. See the section following *The remainder of the draft specification below proposes a further extension to covariant returns of interface methods to be considered later* in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns).

In the meantime, a possible workaround is to make your `ILocationModel` generic like so:

```
public interface IStreetModel
{
    // Properties go here
}

public interface ILocationModel<out T> where T: IStreetModel
{
    T Street { get; }
}

public class StreetModel : IStreetModel
{
    // Properties go here
}

public class LocationModel : ILocationModel<StreetModel>
{
    public StreetModel Street { get; } // This is where my query is
}
```

Of course the most obvious solution is simply to declare the return type of `LocationModel.Street` as `IStreetModel`.

Another alternative is to use explicit interface implementation, like so:

```
public class LocationModel : ILocationModel
{
    public StreetModel Street { get; } // This is where my query is

    IStreetModel ILocationModel.Street => Street;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had recently finished up reading on covariance and in my head, I'm thinking that this should work. Both solutions do the trick though. Out of curiosity, which one is the better practice here?

Comment: I think the second workaround is probably better in this case - it's simpler and means you don't need to change `ILocationModel`.